# Ambari script to get all the components installed on particular host for mentioned cluster name

Tags: hadoop, ambari

Description: Write a unix script , which takes cluster name and host as input and gives components installed on it in text file

A script which takes 2 input as cluster name and host name and provide the output on a text file listing all the installed component on it.

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Comment: A script which takes 2 input as cluster name and host name and provide the output on a text file listing all the installed component on it., have a look.

Answer (score 0):

curl -u admin:password -H "X-Requested-By: XXXX" -X GET  servername/clusters/cluster_name/hosts/Host_name/host_components > output.txt

grep "Component_name" -i output.txt > component.txt

by using these command you can find the components in a single cluster and specific host,, for cluster level you need to run a loop